# Unable to execute this array program in java

Tags: arrays, execute

I am try to execute this code in eclipse but fail. No Compile Error or Runtime Error but still when i click on "Run", This code is not doing anything.Why? Kindly help.

```
 import java.io.*;

 public class Compile {

public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    int size;

    try
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        size = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int[] arr = new int[size+10];

        for(int i=1;i<=size+10;i++)
        {
            arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error in input");
    }

}
```

Comment: What are the inputs you are giving to this code?

Comment: What do you mean by "the code is not doing anything"? Your code expects an initial input for the size of the array. You have to enter the size and then the rest of the program will continue.

Comment: the screen is not being displayed where I can give the inputs.

Comment: Are you still facing the problem?

Comment: No but sometimes my eclipse misbehaves. It does not do any activity when i click that run button on toolbar. Have you ever faced the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your program stops and waits for user input when you call `br.readline()`. Type something (an integer in your case) and press Enter.

Comment: I removed br.readlIne() and wrote Scanner class . Now the eclipse is showing console. Previously it was not. Any reasons why it is behaving like this?

Comment: @AbhishekSharma What do you mean "wrote Scanner class"? Do you mean you used the Scanner class to read an input?

Comment: @AbhishekSharma It shouldn't make a difference then. This is more likely to do with Eclipse itself, as far as I have seen, Eclipse opens up and displays its console view the when you run your program, irregardless if you are waiting for input or printing.